# Compare two different dates in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I try to validate a form. To do validation I want to compare two dates. So I get today date and add seven days to today date.

```
const date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
```

Then I try to compare this date with the input field date.

```
if (values.expiryDate<=date) {
   errors.expiryDate = "Expiry date should not be longer than a week.";
}
```

I try to compare two dates like this. But this code does not validate these two days. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure `values.expiryDate` contains `Date` instance? I suspect it holds ISO string representation and that may cause problems.

Comment: @Aitwar I get the date input from a HTML form and the input type is 'date'. If it holds ISO string representation how should I correct this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the values.expiryDate is in string then first convert it to Date object.

```
const d1 = new Date(values.expiryDate);
```

then you can compare d1 and date easily.

```
if (d1<=date) {
   errors.expiryDate = "Expiry date should not be longer than a week.";
}
```

Comment: I tried this modified code but this also does not validate two dates